# ORDER BY based on SELECTed fields

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Assuming this

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    NAME 'ANY ALIAS', 
    PLACE, 
    TIMESTAMP(OTHER_FIELD_1) 'ALIAS FIELD', 
    ANOTHER_FIELD
FROM MY_TABLE
```

Now I want to order this dynamically, not `ORDER BY ID ASC, NAME DESC, OTHER_FIELD_1 ASC`

but something like `ORDER BY 0 ASC, 1 DESC, 3 ASC`

There's a way/workaround to do this?

Comment: Do you want to sort by one column and different values of this column?

Comment: FWIW I believe column indexes are 1-based, so you should do `ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 DESC, 4 ASC`. Unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: Oh no no. Sorry, probably my fault. The SELECT statement produces an Array. The ID is 0, NAME 'ANY ALIAS' is 1, and so on. Isted of write ID ASC, NAME DESC, I want to write something like ORDER BY 0 ASC, 1 DESC. As if, to explain better, I want to tell to MySQL: "Order The First Field ASC, The second Field DESC" and so on. Without indicating the name, but only the position of SELECT's Array. lc understood me.

Comment: OKOK lc you have avoided me a sleepless night. :) I've considered to be 0-based. And ironically I tried to order just one field, the first. Without doing the test with other numbers (like 1 2 3 4). Many Thanks